# List<Objeto> a String en Java

Tags: java, json, string, lista

Tengo una Lista de un Objeto.

```
public class BusStop {

    private String description;

    private float lat;

    private float lng;

    //getter and setter

}
```

Del cual trato de meter todo su contenido dentro de una variable de tipo String.

He intentado esto:

```
StringBuilder aux = new StringBuilder();
busStop.forEach(aux::append);

return aux.toString();
```

Pero la respuesta que obtengo no es la deseada.

> es.yo.app.model.BusStop@6cdf7f4bes.yo.app.model.BusStop@15820f4bes.yo.app.model.BusStop@2022ad11

Y esto e slo que quiero lograr

> [{"lat":43.482243622643026,"lng":-3.7942432892720035,"description":"1"},{"lat":43.47775946266253,"lng":-3.8052296173970035,"description":"2"},{"lat":43.474520695703184,"lng":-3.822567416469269,"description":"3"}]

Comment: Has repetido la pregunta anterior? Deberías borrarla y editar la que ya estás contestada o hacer una totalmente diferente.

Comment: En la otra no preguntaba como pasar una Lista de objetos a un String. Por eso pense que lo ideal era hacer una nueva Y no hacer muchas preguntas en un mismo post

Comment: Quieres hacer lo contrario de la anterior, es decir, pasarlo a JSON? Mira este tutorial http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial Especialmente la sección 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que está llamando al método toString() y no lo tienes sobreescrito. 
Si no se sobreescribe el método toString() se llama al del padre (en este caso el de Object, padre de todos) y lo que hace es mostrar la representación de la clase y el objeto. [Aquí la documentación al respecto](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Tendrías que crear la sobreescritura más o menos así

```
@Override
public String toString(){
 return "{ lat:" + lat + (otras propiedades) +"}"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es usar `Streams` y `map()`:

```
public List<String> getStringList(List<BusStop> busStopList){
    return busStopList.stream()
           .map(item->getItemAsString(item))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
private String getItemAsString(BusStop busStop){
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    text.append("{");
    text.append("lat=").append(lat).append(",");
    text.append("lng=").append(lng).append(",");
    text.append("description=").append(description);
    text.append("}");
    return text.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes o bien sobreescribir el método toString() de la clase BusStop o definir uno específico que te devuelvan la representación en formato JSON de esa instancia e invocarlo en ese forEach().

Ejemplo:

```
public String generaJSON() {
    String patron = "{\"lat\":%s, \"lng\":%s, \"description\":\"%s\"}";
    return String.format(patron, getLat(), getLng(), getDescription());
}
```

Otra opción sería que mirases librerías tipo FasterXML Jackson para convertir instancias de objetos a string JSON y al revés

Answer (score 1):

Siempre puedes sobreescribir el método toString() de la Clase, de modo que podría ser algo como:

```
@Override
public String toString() { 
     return "{'lat':" + lat + ",'lng':" + lng + ",'description':'" + description + "'}";
}
```

Comment: Me sirvio. Gracias por la ayuda !!

Comment: @Eduardo si te sirvió recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con éste método en la clase `BusStop`.

```
public Staff crearJsonFromObject(BusStop obj) {

        Staff staff = new Staff();

        staff.setLat(obj.getLat());
        staff.setLng(obj.getLng());
        staff.setDescription(obj.getDescription());

        return staff;

    }
```

Salida:

```
{"lat":3423434,"lng":23424242,"description":"wefwefwf"}
```